# I want to delete from particular words in all the line if that particular word is present

Tags: shell-script, command-line, linux-mint, stack

eg:

```
CREATE VIEW AIPKEYITEM.SEASONGROUPNETSALES ( 
CALENDARID , 
PRODUCTGROUPID FOR COLUMN PRDGRPID   , 
NETSALESDOLLARS FOR COLUMN NETSA00001 , 
NETSALESUNITS FOR COLUMN NETSA00002 ) 
AS 
SELECT  
        (SELECT MIN(CALENDARID)  
            FROM AIPKEYITEM.KEYIT00002  
            WHERE FISCALYEAR = CAL.FISCALYEAR  
            AND FISCALSEASON = CAL.FISCALSEASON) CALENDARID  
    , PRODUCTGROUPID  
    , SUM(NETSALESDOLLARS) NETSALESDOLLARS  
    , SUM(NETSALESUNITS) NETSALESUNITS  
    FROM AIPKEYITEM.KEYIT00002 CAL  
    INNER JOIN AIPKEYITEM.WEEKG00001 WEEKGROUPORGUNITUNITSDOLLARS  
    ON CAL.CALENDARID = WEEKGROUPORGUNITUNITSDOLLARS.CALENDARID  
    GROUP BY CAL.FISCALYEAR, CAL.FISCALSEASON, PRODUCTGROUPID ;
```

In the above example I want to remove entire word starting from FOR COLUMN in which line it is present.

Comment: welcomme to U&L, please edit you post with: what is the expected result ? what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
cat myscript | sed 's/FOR COLUMN.*$//g' > myscript.filtered
```

when `myscript` is the name of the file which is shown above?  Is that what you wish to achieve?

Comment: Great.  Since it is working please mark my answer as such, thanks.